# Function already exists VIM

Tags: vim

I have defined a function in my `/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` file. The problem is that every time I open a `.py` file, I get the `E122: Function MyFunction already exists, add ! to replace it`.

I know that if I add `!` then it will override the function (which is not a problem), but that means that it will replace it everytime, and it is a useless (and not very clean) supplementary action.

I guess that the problem come from the Python configuration file being sourced again and again every time I open a new `.py` file.

How can I tell VIM to source only once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend putting the function in an autoload directory. (Read `:help autoload` it does a very good job explaining how this works). The quick version is below.

Edit the file `~/.vim/autoload/ftplugin/python.vim` and add your function there. Everything after the autoload is part of the function signiture. (Instead of `/` use `#` between directories and leave off the .vim for the filename `directory(s)#file#FunctionName`)

```
function ftplugin#python#MyFunction()
    ...
endfunction
```

This function will automatically be loaded by vim the first time it is used.

Inside the filetype plugin you would just create the necessary mappings and commands.

```
command -buffer MyFunction call ftplugin#python#MyFunction()
nnoremap <buffer> <leader>m :call ftplugin#python#MyFunction()<CR>
```

and the function will automatically be loaded when it is called the first time. And other buffer that loads the ftplugin won't run into the redefinition problem.

Comment: Seems to be a very clean solution. I'm just curious what do you think about @VanLaser answer (see below), considering that it is easier to implement. Is it not as clean as it looks?

Comment: @tomasyany his first way is generally the way plugins do include guards. They aren't normally in ftplugins but normal plugins which normally get sourced once (and don't benefit from lazy loading). The second way I would claim to be iffy because some other plugin might have created MyFunction. Which might not be the same as your definition. (Also autoload functions allow you to namespace your functions, only problem is the function names are now longer)

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for you very clear explanation :).

Comment: The takeaway from this is to keep ftplugins for _local_ stuff: local options, local variables, local maps, and the like.  Functions in Vim are global by default, thus they don't belong in ftplugins.

Answer (score 2):

**One way**: define a variable at the end of the file, check for its existence at the beginning (similar to a c include guard):

```
if exists('g:my_python')
  finish
endif

fun MyFunction
  ...
endfun

" ... other stuff

let g:my_python = 1
```

**Another way** (if all you have is this function): check directly for the existence of its definition:

```
if !exists('*MyFunction')
  fun MyFunction
    ...
  endfun
endif
```

Comment: The first solution is a pretty bad idea.  Ftplugins are supposed to run every time you open a file of the of the corresponding type.  It normally deals with setting variables local to the buffer and the like.  With your solution this is done only for the first buffer, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: BTW, you can find the second solution used in ... `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` for function `<SID>Python_jump`.

Comment: You are confused.  Something resembling your second solution is in the standard runtime, yes.  However, please note that (1) the version in the standard runtime refers to a `<SID>` function (which can't live in any other file), and (2) the function is actually defined with `fun!`.  (It also puts an end to any and all fun with `endfun`, but somehow that's less relevant here.)

Comment: And why is `fun!` relevant there (instead of `fun`), when used inside that `!exists(...)` check?

Comment: Because (1) the initial question was about avoiding the bang `!`, and (2) your solution does avoid it, and that's wrong.  If a function named `MyFunction` is defined in another file (and presumably does something unrelated), you don't want to use _that_ instead of your `MyFunction`.

Comment: I mean, what's the relevance of `fun!` instead of `fun` for `<SID>Python_jump`, when enclosed already in the `!exists(...)` check.

Comment: Probably none, in the context of the runtime file (although using `fun!` instead of `fun` is generally a good practice).  But it is relevant in the context of your solution, as I pointed out above. _shrug_

Comment: I just pointed out that your original point (2) is void. Have fun.

Comment: It isn't.  Should your function have used `fun!`, it would have been correct.  As it is, it's fun only if you like debugging Vim code. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) plugin would be great to have a snippet like:

```
snippet guard "add guard to functions" b
if !exists('*`!p
try:
    func_name = re.search('\S+\s+(\S+)\(', snip.v.text.splitlines()[0]).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    func_name = ''
snip.rv = func_name
`')
    ${VISUAL}
endif
${0:jump here <C-j>}
endsnippet
```

It allow us to select a function with `vip`, trigger the `guard` snippet and fix 
any function with no effort. In the post quoted you can see a complete explanation about the code above

It came from a discussion on [vim @stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19343/). Actually I already knew about `!exists` thing, so I was trying to create a snippet to make my snippets smarter.